# Not getting first character after an attempt to downcast an object in java using charAt();

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the first character from the Object after attempting to downcast the object but my code seems to be missing something I don't know what's wrong.

```
String name = "Mike";
```

if I try the charAt() method it works fine using the above code.

```
name.charAt(0);
```

gives us "M". right?

I tried to downcast(not sure if that's the right term) the object say:

```
Object obj = (String) name;

obj ==> "Mike"; // is what we get
```

But if I use the method:

```
obj.charAt(0);
```

I'm expecting the same result "M" but it gives me an error instead. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you read the error? Your variable is still declared as `Object`.

Comment: obj is not a String variable. It may refer to a String object but is not a String type and so has none of the methods of String (unless you cast -- which is dangerous). Note that this is information found in the first 1-2 chapters of any Java book. Please have a look as it won't be time wasted.

Comment: Also this `Object obj = (String) name;` is the same as `Object obj = name;`

Comment: charAt is a method for String objects, not for Objects. Maybe try this: `(String) obj.charAt(0);`

Comment: You can solve it but downcasting the object when you invoke the mthod upon it: `Object name = "Mike"; System.out.println(((String)name).charAt(0));`

Comment: As friends above said, you should cast `obj` to String to be able to use `charAt()` like: `((String)obj).charAt(0);` because `Object` doesn't seem to support `charAt()` and whatever `obj` is referencing it is `Object` and nothing knows about it being `String`.

Comment: @Dani: test first before giving bad advice. It must be `((String) obj).charAt(0);` To Arcee -- casting has dangers, since you don't know if obj has at some point changed the type of object that it references. Avoid doing it if possible.

Comment: `obj.toString().charAt(0)` is safe, but whether it produces anything meaningful is a different question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks for the advice. Ill put that in mind. At this point I'm really trying to understand this subject...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that by assigning `String name` to `Object obj` you hide that whatever is `obj` referencing to, is a `String`.

Of course you can cast `obj` to `String` by using

```
(String)obj
```

because underlying reference is an reference to object of type `String`.

You have to consider that as `obj` is an `Object` it might be whatever type your language supports (is it Java?) so that's why you are getting error when executing `obj.chatAt(0)`.

What would you expect it to return if underlying reference was to e.g. Integer?

That's why to use `charAt()` you have to cast it back to `String`

```
String str = (String)obj;
char ch = str.charAt(0);
```

Or simpler:

```
char ch = ((String)obj).charAt(0);
```

keeping in mind, that if `obj`'s reference changed in meantime to e.g. some Integer, you won't succeed at casting probably throwing another error / exception.

P.S. Sample code is assuming, that your language is using `char` as type that is meant to contain single character.

Answer (score 1):

obj is a `Object` not a `String` so that it does not have the `charAt()` method. If you already know your object is type of String then you can cast it `((String) obj).charAt(0)` or you can using: `obj.toString().charAt(0)`

Comment: Did you see any one using `toString` method?

Comment: Oh.. both work well.. thanks so much... although I can't really wrap my head around typecasting right now... :(

Answer (score 1):

Well, **Casting** means taking an Object of one particular type and *turning it into* another Object type.

**Downcast** means taking the Object and casting it into a more *specific* type of Object. For example:

```
Object obj = "This is an object";
String s = (String)obj;
```

Now you can *invoke* the methods in the ***String*** Class upon the `String s` object. But not the opposite. So you cannot invoke ***Directly*** the methods that exist in ***String Class*** upon an instance of ***Class Object***.

To use the method `charAt(int index)` in the above example on the `Object obj` directly, you need to ***downcast*** first then you can go ahead:

```
((String)obj).charAt(0); // it will give "T";
```

Furthermore, If I do:

```
obj.charAt(0);
```

And when I try to compile it, it gives me this error:

```
The method charAt(int) is undefined for the type Object
```

Which basically means that method doesn't exist in `Object` Class.